# Speed up pandas pairwise creation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am looking to speed up a pandas dataframe groupby function to do a pairwise comparison.

For a given dataframe, it has columns [x1, x2, x3, x4] with many rows. (there are millions of rows)

I want to group-by [ x1]. (there will be tens of thousands of groups)

Then take the first row of every group-by, duplicate the row N number of times, where N is the number of rows in the group-by.
Rename the column headers to:  [y1, y2, y3, y4]
then merge it with the original group.

My original table with header:

```
[x1, x2, x3, x4]
[1, 'p', 45, 62]
[1, 'k', 12, 84]
```

Turn to:

```
[y1, y2, y3, y4, x1, x2, x3, x4]
[1, 'p', 45, 62, 1, 'p', 45, 62]
[1, 'p', 45, 62, 1, 'k', 12, 84]
```

I can multi-process it, but it is still pretty slow, my current version.

```
for name, group in dataframe.groupby(['x1']):
    # take first row and make dataframe
    duplicated_row = pd.concat([group.iloc[[0]]]*len(group), ignore_index = True)

    # create new headers
    new_headers = [x.replace('v2', 'v1') for x in list(duplicated_row)]
    column_names2 = dict(zip(list(duplicated_row), new_headers))

    # rename headers
    duplicated_row = duplicated_row.rename(index=str, columns=column_names2)
    duplicated_row = duplicated_row.reset_index(drop=True)

    # concat two dataframes
    full_df = pd.concat([duplicated_row, group.reset_index(drop=True)], axis = 1)
```

Are there any functions I can pull from pandas which are native C to speed this?  or vectorize this somehow? (at entire dataframe, or by the groupby level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform`, and `concat` the results.

```
i = df['x1'].rename('y1')
j = df.groupby('x1').transform('first')
j.columns = 'y' + j.columns.str[1:]

df = pd.concat([i, j, df], axis=1)
print(df)
   y1 y2  y3  y4  x1 x2  x3  x4
0   1  p  45  62   1  p  45  62
1   1  p  45  62   1  k  12  84
```